# Simplifying locality search

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I'm working on a property portal (to be developed in asp.net MVC) that allow users to search properties in specific region or city.
I created tables for Country, State, City and Region.
all these tables refers to one another in right to left direction, means Region referes to CityId, Cities refers to StateId etc.

I have a web page with single textbox which takes input as state, city, region or zipcode or just say any locality
I don't want user to select state then city and then region, User should be able to search directly with city, region or zip with single textbox

How can I get this job done with my current table structure? Do I need to change my table structure?

Answer (score 0):

Either use drop downs making one depend upon another else if you need a text search make them enter in a word or words and search each table for the keyword